# Creating excel sheet from template in Java, new versions of Excel 

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf, excel-template

I found the following code to create a excel sheet from an existing template with formats and add data to it and save it to a new file

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(
            new FileInputStream("template.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new  HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);
Will load an xls, preserving its structure (macros included). You can then modify it,

HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Data"); ...
```

and then save it.

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("new.xls"); 
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

This works absolutely fine. But my issue is that I am dealing with new versions of excel now. So I need to develop a similar code to handle new version of template. Can someone suggest how can I do this? I tried changing HSSWorkbook to XSSFWorkbook. however XSSFWorkbook doesn't have a constructor that lets me pass a boolean. Also. when i tried it, it copies the data but the rows with data do not retain the formatting of the columns that the template has.

Comment: which version of POI are you using?

Answer (score 9):

This should work fine (though it's always best to use the latest version of POI for all the bug fixes):

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook( OPCPackage.open("template.xlsx") );
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

// Make changes to the sheet
sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).setCellValue("Changed value"); // For example

// All done
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("new.xls"); 
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

If you code against the interfaces, then you can just swap between HSSF and XSSF in your constructor, and have your code work for both formats

Comment: I tried the above code.I get the following error                                            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:68)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:129)
at com.caremark.eztest.common.utilities.CSVToExcelFileConverter.convertCSVToXLSComprehensive(CSVToExcelFileConverter.java:80) at

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of POI, and you've included all the [Jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html)

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr I noticed i didnt have the jar in runtime environment. That exception is gone now but getCell() on the row is returning null and so i need to create a new cell in the row

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr I noticed i didnt have the jar in runtime environment. That exception is gone now but getCell() on the row is returning null and so i need to create a new cell in the row and it doesnt copy the formatting of the template

Answer (score 3):

I used XSSF and it is working fine.

```
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("template.xlsx"));           
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("new.xlsx");
        //Sheet mySheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Summary");
        XSSFRow row = sheet1.getRow(15);
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("Bharthan");

        wb.write(fileOut);
        log.info("Written xls file");
        fileOut.close();
```

Just need to add this dependency in pom.xml of maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
```